# Can i create nested tables on MySql?

Tags: mysql

for example,access example db, every student record have a nested table about guardians.
http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/9881/53882937.jpg

Comment: How do you mean nested? Is this different from adding extra "GuardianName, GuardianEmail" columns, or adding a GuardianDetails (or more generally Contact) table and then FKRing to it from your student table, or something else?

Comment: adding table into table,in example guardians are in student record

Comment: Is it really a "nested table"?  That looks like a UI that shows Guardians for the selected Student.  In the list of Tables on the left side, I see both Students and Guardians.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Something like that is almost always done as a single mapping table for all students, with a foreign key column pointing to the `student` table to specify which student a particular row relates to.

You then just filter the table to match a given student, and present that list without a student column, in the UI. It looks like a separate table to the user, but that's not actually how it's stored.

(If you *did* create a separate `guardians` table for each student, you'd make it impossible to do queries like ‘find students for a particular guardian’.)

Comment: Alternatively, if e.g. you wanted to track the guardian records for siblings together, you can use a join table: i.e. have a student table, a guardian table (without the student FKR) and then a 'student-guardian' table with just pairs of student ID and guardian ID, each FKRed to the appropriate table. You then have a many-to-many mapping between students and guardians. (This may be what the 'students and guardians' table is in your screenshot.) Although in this case you might want to move the 'relationship' value into the join table.